# Is there a way to increase the CMPedometer update frequency?

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, core-motion

I am building an app to detect user steps. The requirement is to count the steps close to real-time.
Currently, I am using CMPedometer. However, based on several tests, I noticed that the CMPedometer update frequency is quite slow.

It is taking at least 10 steps to start updating, then subsequently updating every 4 or 5 steps.
Eg: If the total number of steps (manually counted) is 50, CMPedometer returns values as below

10, 14, 16, 20, 27, 31, 35, 39, 44, 48

The pattern is more or less the same for multiple tests.

Is there any way to optimize or increase the frequency of getting updates from the CMPedometer?

Below is my current code snippet.

```
if CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() {
          pedometer.startUpdates(from: Date()) { pedometerData, error in
            guard let pedometerData = pedometerData, error == nil else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.pedometerSteps = pedometerData.numberOfSteps.intValue
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Docs doesn't mention that configuration https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmpedometer/1613950-startupdates.  So I think it needs some calculation (algorithm) to make sure steps count is correct before send to handler.

Comment: I think that there is probably a machine learning algorithm involved to remove noise and increase accuracy.  The result is a delay but more accurate data

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I write some sort of algorithm using accelorometer data to simulate the steps in between Pedometer steps.